# Is there a way to prevent Formtastic from overriding "type" parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, formtastic

I am using a jquery plugin for a datetime picker, and it requires the type parameter to be set to 'text'.

So I tried the normal method:

```
= semantic_form_for @schedule do |f|
  = f.input :start_at, :as => :datetime_picker, :input_html => { :class=> 'datetimepicker', :type => 'text' }
```

But Formtastic is overriding that type and setting it to datetime-local.

```
<input id="datetimepicker" maxlength="16" name="schedule[start_at]" size="16" step="1" type="datetime-local">
```

Is there a way to negate Formtastic automatically setting the type, without changing the gem?

Answer (score 0):

So, I realised that I was heading down the wrong path and that if I wanted it be of the text type, it should be a string or text input. Which went against my original thinking that if I want a datetime picker, I should tell formtastic, when I should have only been telling the jquery plugin.

Here is what my haml looks like now:

```
= semantic_form_for @schedule do |f|
  = f.input :start_at, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => 'datetimepicker', :type => 'text' }
```